# .NET Web browser component that allow you to capture the GET and POST data

Tags: .net, components, gui-testing

I'd like to develop an .NET application, where you navigate in a website and the app records the GET and POST data you send to the server, so later on you can reproduce it programatically.

I've been taking a look on the WinForm's WebBrowser component but I see no way to get the POST data I'm sending.

Do you know of any component (even not free) that allow you to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/):

> FiddlerCore allows you to integrate HTTP/HTTPS traffic viewing and modification capabilities into your .NET application

Comment: but it seems like has no gui ... I don't see how can I do what I want with it :(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could bypass making the application and just use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp).